# empty JSON export with after effects + bodymovin for Lottie

Tags: json, after-effects, bodymovin, lottie

I have a basic animation in After Effects, installed bodymovin (without any errors), and would like to export as a Lottie Animation.
But **all I get when exporting is an empty JSON file**.

I do select my composition during the export of course and I only have one composition.

I checked the [tips and guidelines](http://airbnb.io/lottie/after-effects/general-tips.html), and also the [supported features](http://airbnb.io/lottie/after-effects/supported-features.html),
but I didn't find anything odd that I should not be doing.

Here's a screenshot of my animation:
[image: after effects basic anim]

Any ideas?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it, of course it's just me being stupid...

I (re)installed After Effects before and forgot about the setting to allow  scripts (used for the exporting) to write files.

For future purposes: listen to the bunny. :Đ

[image]